# How to auto increment and array and print it in a for loop – PHP

Tags: php, arrays, increment

I have a for each loop.
Each loop is to calls array by name with the incremented number in the back.
I can call the array manually, but when i try to auto increment it prints the entire string.
Example shown below

1. This works

`<?php echo $one_month_plan1['one_month_price'] ?>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGsMu.png)

2. This does not.
   `$<?php echo $one_month_plan . $i . ['one_month_price']; ?>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dgGa.png)

Comment: _Why_ do you have numbered variable names in the first place, why is this not just an array named `$one_month_plan` to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some array like this and a index to loop on:

You can use $GLOBALS to access, But my suggestion is to rethink what you are trying to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$some_index = [1,2];

$one_month_plan1=[
"one_month_price"=>"100"
];

$one_month_plan2=[
"one_month_price"=>"200"
];

foreach ($some_index as $i) {
  echo "<br>". $GLOBALS["one_month_plan{$i}"]["one_month_price"];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]